# Different test_set and train_set dimensionalities after removing columns with high percentual of missing values

Tags: machine-learning, imputation

I'm currently having a problem with a fraud detection project. The dataset is already Split in train and test set so initially I had a 0.7 Split with the test set containing 393 columns and the train set containing 394 as expected, but when I removed the columns with high percentage of missing values (> 73%) I've got 15 columns that stayed in the test set but not in the train. Should I simply remove these columns? Or maybe copy them to the training set and proceed with the imputation? Is the latter prejudicial to the generalization of the model? Sorry for the ignorance, I'm kind of newbie in this field, thank you!

Comment: There is no point at all in maintaining columns in the test set that are not present in the training data

Answer (score 0):

When you do machine learning, always remember the test set is not know in the moment you are developing your algorithm. It is called test set, because you are testing.

> Should I simply remove these columns?

Your decision only should depend on the training set. if you remove a column in the training set, you **have** to remove it in the test set.

> Or maybe copy them to the training set and proceed with the
>   imputation?

Super worse idea! You would use information form the test set. Imagen you would add a column with the prediction value already, this would be also wrong, this are oyu doing if you use information from test set for your training set.

> Is the latter prejudicial to the generalization of the model?

Never use information from the test set for your training set!